# Expired session error (admin) when I try to make a call to WooCommerce api

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, api, session

I have activated the WooCommerce API that is mounted on the WP, the administrator session expires every 2 hours, the problem is that when I try to make a call to the WooCommerce API, it returns a 200 http code with a html page in the body indicating that my session has expired due to inactivity ..

I do not understand why WP denies me access because the connection to the API is done through a Key and a Secret.

Someone knows how I can solve this problem without having to increase the WP session.

The highlighted text "Tu sesion ha caducado ya que han pasado mas de 120 minituos desde el ultimo acceso. Por favor, vuelve a iniciar la sesion para continuar" in English is --> "Your session has expired since more than 120 minutes have passed since the last access, please restart the session to continue"

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like a bug that needs raising with the WooCommerce team ( that they don't use appropriate HTTP codes )